# Nodeclipse: crashing when debugging (Mars, JDK 8, Win10)

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, v8, chromium, nodeclipse

When debugging, any console logging that outputs an object is terminating the debugger.  Example:

```
var obj = {"an": "object"};
console.log("this will fail", obj);
```

stack trace:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.8.0_73
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/Jeff/workspace_trid/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.chromium.debug.core
Info
Sat Feb 13 11:49:26 PST 2016
SDK:org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection: Shutdown requested

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:88)
    at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.Message.fromBufferedReader(Message.java:134)
    at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection$ReaderThread.run(SocketConnection.java:166)
```

JSON.stringify of same will also crash the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use Enide 2015 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nodeclipse/files/ ?

If there problem is still there with Enide distribution, raise issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/

Comment: Thanks for responding, Paul.  I downloaded Enide 2015 and opened my existing Mars workspace.  Loaded fine, but when debugging it still terminates on console dumps of objects.

Comment: Other than the stack trace, what other Eclipse config information would be helpful?

Comment: Just follow at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/206 SO is not for discussions